# A quote in a program

Tags: rebus, movies

Given the following bash program:

```
sleep 120
exit
echo "nothing"
```

What movie quote is this referencing?

Comment: For curiosity's sake, should we take this as a trick question, or pretend that the script wouldn't end after `exit`? :)

Comment: The script intentionally ends :3

Comment: can't figure it out. Words I considered that might be included in the title: sleeping, waiting, 2 minutes, leaving, not saying a thing, without saying nothing

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Is it

> Wait a minute, wait a minute - you ain't heard nothin' yet...
>
>  From [The Jazz Singer (1927)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0018037/)

Reason

> sleep 120 - waiting a minute twice, then it's exiting the program before 'nothing' is outputted

Comment: If true, would be better with two lines of sleep 60.

Comment: @Devsman or even better two lines of "sleep 1m" although that might make it too easy.

Answer (score 5):

I believe it's

> "If you can't say something nice, don't say nothing at all" from Bambi

Reason:

> Sleep 120 gives you time to think of something nice to say. AS you couldn't, you don't say nothing, because the script has exited before you can say nothing

Answer (score 3):

It is referencing to

> Alfred Hitchcock - The Birds

Reason

> It lasts 120 minutes and has no ending credits

But I might be missing something since I can only figure out a movie title, not really a quote from this movie.

Comment: Hahaha nice explanation, it sounds more like a punchline